# How to calculate P&L for a given period of time

Tags: trading, currency

Let's say I have a currency trading app. I start with $100 USD, and after 4 weeks, though trades, I now have $200 USD. My P&L would be 100$ or up $100.

```
So the calc would be: P&L = start_value - current_value
```

Now, in a similar scenario, I start the month with $100 USD, 2 weeks later I add $50 USD, 2 weeks later I now have $200 USD. How do I calculate the P&L for the last four weeks, considering I added $50 in the middle?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "P&L = start_value - current_value - contributions"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say

```
P/L_1 = V - $100
P/L_2 = $200 - (v + $50) = $150 - V
```

So that gives us the profit or loss for the first two weeks and then the second two weeks (`V` is the value at two weeks, when you add the $50).  But if we add those, the `V` cancels out and we get:

```
P/L = P/L_1 + P/L_2 = $150 - $100 = $50
```

So in general, we could say

```
P/L = final value - (sum of contributions)
```

If we wanted to make things complicated, we could try to include inflation.  The $50 two weeks from now is worth less than half the $100 now.  Or the $200 at the end is worth less than twice the $100 now.  But it can be difficult to calculate inflation for periods less than a month, as they don't usually report it more often than that.  It's more something that you would do when calculating an annual number or a number for multiple years.